# Posgres in python (psycopg2) INSERT INTO statement hangs/freezes without inserting or crashing

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm attempting to insert data into my `persons` table. I've tried both by using a cursor in python `cursor.execute(sql)`, and by connecting to the database with the terminal and inserting there. However, the program simply stops at the point of execution. **I commit at the end**. The table is empty and looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons(
  AKey INT PRIMARY KEY, -- Person ID primary key
  Name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- Person name
  Website VARCHAR(256), -- URL for persons website
  IKey INT REFERENCES Institutions -- Institution affiliation 
);
```

And an example insert looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO persons (Akey, Name, Website, IKey) VALUES(1, 'John Smith', 'www.foo.bar', 1);
```

The insert is not made, nor does it produce an error. The terminal or python just stops at the insert statement, apparently not doing anything. Inserting into other tables works without any problems.

EDIT:
I should mention that I am the only one doing transactions on this database, which only contains empty tables.

Comment: The query should fail.  If all tables are empty, the institution with Ikey1 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are blocked on a lock.  See [Lock Monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring).  Some other session has done something which conflicts with yours, such as inserting a person with the same akey or name as you are trying to insert, or deleting the row from institutions which you are trying to reference, and that session has not committed.  Now your session is waiting to see if that other one commits or rolls back.

Comment: This was the way to go, previous attempts to populate the table had bugged out and never been closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to commit your query.

A full example looks like this:

```py
import contextlib

import psycopg2

db_config = dict(database="...", user="...", password="...")

with contextlib.closing(psycopg2.connect(**db_config)) as connection:
    try:
        with contextlib.closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO persons (Akey, Name, Website, IKey) VALUES(1, 'John Smith', 'www.foo.bar', 1);"
            cursor.execute(sql)
        connection.commit()
    except:
        connection.rollback()
        raise
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, thank you for commenting. I do commit my query at the end, however as the program hangs at cursor.execute(sql), it never gets to the commit statement.